# Add (+/-) Button Number Increment

Tags: oracleforms

I need to create number increasing and decreasing button in forms 11g. I will much appreciate if some one can provide me the code.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two push buttons in Oracle forms one is for + and give the label + and another for - and give the label -.

Put the following code on when-button-pressed trigger for + button:

```
Begin
   :yourblock.textitem := :yourblock.textitem + 1;
End;
```

For - button:

```
Begin
  :yourblock.textitem := :yourblock.textitem - 1;
End;
```

Comment: Many thanks Vinish Kapoor you are genius. its working fine.